# ng-zorro - Linear ProgressBar is not showing

Tags: angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

My HTML:

```
<nz-progress [nzPercent]="pos?.positionProportion" nzStrokeColor="red" [nzType]="circle"></nz-progress>
<nz-progress [nzPercent]="pos?.positionProportion" nzStrokeColor="red"></nz-progress>
<nz-progress [nzPercent]="pos?.positionProportion" nzStrokeColor="red" [nzType]="line"></nz-progress>
```

My TS:

```
circle: string = 'circle'
line: string = 'line'
```

My view:

[image]

As you can see, only the circle (and dashboard) displays. It is not a space problem, I tried on a new blank page and nothing happened either.

Can I get a hand here? What am I missing?

Edit: All other ng-zorro components I tried work, all of them. The problem is just on this one and the line one.

Comment: Can you specify the version you used for `angular`, `ng-zorro-antd`, and `@ant-design/icons-angular` ?

Comment: @YongShun i fixed it but don't really know how.. it was a really weird css interaction. I was putting the component inside these css classes:
.modal_row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 5px 2px;
} 
and another class with just
text-shadow: 0 0 0.2px #1e1e1e;

Once i took out from there, it displayed for some reason, maybe was a classed inherited too.
My angular version 11.2.5
My ng-zorro-antd 12.0.0
My @ant-design/icons-angular 12.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Suspect your `.modal-row` style with

```
.modal-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

has conflict with `.ant-progress` style as it uses `inline-block`.

```
&-outer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  .@{progress-prefix-cls}-show-info & {
    margin-right: ~'calc(-2em - 8px)';
    padding-right: ~'calc(2em + 8px)';
  }
}

&-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: @progress-remaining-color;
  border-radius: @progress-radius;
}

&-success-bg,
&-bg {
  position: relative;
  background-color: @progress-default-color;
  border-radius: @progress-radius;
  transition: all 0.4s @ease-out-circ 0s;
}
```

---

### Solution

Would suggest wrapping the `<nz-progress>` element in a `<div>` element with a defined width.

Note: *May refer to [Mini size progress bar](https://ng.ant.design/components/progress/en#components-progress-demo-line-mini) as this sample wraps `<nz-progress>` element in a `<div>` element.*

```
<div style="width: 100%">
  <nz-progress [nzPercent]="pos?.positionProportion" nzStrokeColor="red" nzType="line"></nz-progress>
</div>
```

[Sample solution on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-varahamihira-2v2xu)

---

### Reference(s)

[NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd Index.less](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/progress/style/index.less)